# How do I clear this setInterval inside a function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, dom-events

Normally, I’d set the interval to a variable and then clear it like `var the_int = setInterval(); clearInterval(the_int);` but for my code to work I put it in an anonymous function:

```
function intervalTrigger() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (timedCount >= markers.length) {
      timedCount = 0;
    }

    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[timedCount], "click");
    timedCount++;
  }, 5000);
};

intervalTrigger();
```

How do I clear this? I gave it a shot and tried `var test = intervalTrigger(); clearInterval(test);` to be sure, but that didn’t work.

Basically, I need this to stop triggering once my Google Map is clicked, e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
  //stop timer
});
```

Answer (score 273, accepted):

The `setInterval` method returns a handle that you can use to clear the interval. If you want the function to return it, you just return the result of the method call:

```
function intervalTrigger() {
  return window.setInterval( function() {
    if (timedCount >= markers.length) {
       timedCount = 0;
    }
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[timedCount], "click");
    timedCount++;
  }, 5000 );
};
var id = intervalTrigger();
```

Then to clear the interval:

```
window.clearInterval(id);
```

Comment: note: you don't need to reference the global scope. `setInterval` works just as well as `window.setInterval`.

Comment: It's often good practice to be explicit. Some linters will complain about implicit use of global scope, whereas `window.` is ok.

Answer (score 11):

```
// Initiate set interval and assign it to intervalListener
var intervalListener = self.setInterval(function () {someProcess()}, 1000);
function someProcess() {
  console.log('someProcess() has been called');
  // If some condition is true clear the interval
  if (stopIntervalIsTrue) {
    window.clearInterval(intervalListener);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
the_int=window.clearInterval(the_int);
```

Answer (score -4):

### Simplest way I could think of: add a class.

Simply add a class (on any element) and check inside the interval if it's there. This is more reliable, customisable and cross-language than any other way, I believe.

```js
var i = 0;
this.setInterval(function() {
  if(!$('#counter').hasClass('pauseInterval')) { //only run if it hasn't got this class 'pauseInterval'
    console.log('Counting...');
    $('#counter').html(i++); //just for explaining and showing
  } else {
    console.log('Stopped counting');
  }
}, 500);

/* In this example, I'm adding a class on mouseover and remove it again on mouseleave. You can of course do pretty much whatever you like */
$('#counter').hover(function() { //mouse enter
    $(this).addClass('pauseInterval');
  },function() { //mouse leave
    $(this).removeClass('pauseInterval');
  }
);

/* Other example */
$('#pauseInterval').click(function() {
  $('#counter').toggleClass('pauseInterval');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#counter {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #009afd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#counter.pauseInterval {
  border-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<!-- you'll need jQuery for this. If you really want a vanilla version, ask -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p id="counter">&nbsp;</p>
<button id="pauseInterval">Pause/unpause</button></p>
```