# How can I stop a function early?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a timed function that delays for 9 second after the page loads before starting. However, I would like it to be cancelled if a user interacts with the div it is affecting. Here is my code for the function being called.

```
function buttonchange4(){
  $(".button4").css("backgroundColor","yellow").delay(3000).queue(function(next4){
  $(".button4").css("backgroundColor","silver");
     next4();
  });
};

var buttonshow3;
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button4").delay(9200).queue(function(nextoooo){
      buttonchange4();
      buttonshow3 = setInterval( buttonchange4, 12000);
      nextoooo();
  });
});
```

And here is my code for stopping the function.

```
$('.button4').click(function(){
   $( ".button4" ).stop();
   clearInterval(buttonshow3);
   $('.button4').css("backgroundColor","yellow");
});
```

For some reason, after the delay of 3 seconds it still changes the background color of the button to silver... It seems to stop the delay function and jump straight to `buttonchange4();` How can I stop this?

Comment: By using return.

Comment: I think it's the setInterval the problem ... try to clear the setInterval like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901108/how-do-i-clear-this-setinterval)

Comment: Why do you have a delay AND a setInterval? Nested no less.

Comment: I need it to run every 12 seconds, starting 9 seconds after the page is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return;` breaks and stops the function

if you want to break the TimeInterval you can do it this way:

```
var i = setInterval(FunctionA, 1000);
clearInterval( i );
```

or you can stop the `delay()` with `dequeue();`:

```
$( ".button4" ).dequeue();
```

Comment: I managed to clear the interval using the code above, but it would still run the buttonchange4() function once before ending it.

Comment: @user3362196 dont you need to ``dequeue();`` instead of ``stop()`` ? like ``$( ".button4" ).dequeue();``

Comment: Thank you! dequeue worked perfectly. I was using the wrong command to stop the function.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's delay function doesn't offer a way to cancel it ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)).

So I recommend using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`, like so:

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    // do something
}, 9000)
function cancel() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
}
```