# How can I display date and time in Angular template and keep it updated?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-template

I need to display date and time in my angular template, and keep it updated, so when time is changed to show changed time ofcourse, ***application SHOULD look*** like this:

this is my .html template code:

```
<div class="top-right pull-right">
  <button type="button" class="btn xbutton-rectangle" (click)="logOut()">
    <div class="icon-user pull-left">
      <i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="button-text">{{employee.FullName}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="time-date pull-right">
      <p class="button-time">08:55</p>
      <p class="button-date">22.06.2018</p>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

My `.ts` file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-screen',
  templateUrl: './main-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-screen.component.css']
})
export class MainScreenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //.. some methods 
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }

  logOut() {
    this._globals.isAuthenticated = false;
    this._globals.loggedInUser = null;
    this._globals.token = null;
  }

}
```

So how can I display date and time? and keep it updated when system date&time changes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All you need to do is use the setInterval on your constructor

```
  date:Date; 
  constructor(){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.date = new Date()
    }, 1000)
  }
```

And use the date pipe to format the date and time

```
{{date   | date: "MM-dd-yyyy"}}
{{date   | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4ymmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Isn't set interval bad for performances? and why in constructor?

Comment: depend on how you are using it. u need to know when to or not to cancel the interval using `clearInterval` otherwise memory gonna get overwhelmed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901108/how-do-i-clear-this-setinterval?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I don't know.. maybe on component destroy or ? I don't know where is a good place and when to do it?

Comment: what If I rarely go to another component? so ngDestroy is called rarely, that it's dangerous to call clearnInterval rarely?? /for example I stay on same screen for 1-2 days/?  :P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034107/does-javascript-setinterval-method-cause-memory-leak

Comment: Should use Capital 'MM' for month, i was getting minute value instead of month.. {{date   | date: "MM-dd-yyyy"}}

Answer (score 2):

You should assign a variable to the date and update it every 0.1 second for example

```
public today = Date.now();

 setInterval(() => {
      this.today = Date.now();
    }, 100);
```

You can display it in your html like this if you want hours and minutes for example:

```
{{today | date:'HH:mm' }}
```

Look at https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe for other Date format

Comment: to display date: `{{today | date:'dd LLLL yyyy' }}`

Comment: Better than setInterval is to user the Observable, so your will not run into a performance issues. Also if you the unsubscribe into the onDestroy method it's fine.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I'm not an expert on Observable but you should post it as an aswer if you believe it's a better way !

Comment: Looking forward to this, if there is no reply about it I will post mine with a plunker and an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Because I love RxJS, I made a service using it, create a ClockService with this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { interval, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClockService {

  constructor() { }

  getClock() : Observable<Date> {
    return interval(1000).pipe(
      mergeMap(() => of(new Date()))
    )
  }
}
```

And inject your service in your component.ts file like that:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  clock: Observable<Date>;

  constructor(private clockService: ClockService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clock = this.clockService.getClock();
  }
  
}
```

Then finally, use it in your html like that, you can adjust the date filter as you want from the [Angular DatePipe Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

```
{{ clock | async | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}
```

Comment: is there a particular advantage to using `mergeMap(() => of(new Date()))` compared to just `map(x=>new Date())` seems unnecessary to map another `Observable`.  Also `timer(0, 1000)` would return the first `Date()` immediately instead of 1 second later

Answer (score 0):

Just add New function in your component like this

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'main-screen',
      templateUrl: './main-screen.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./main-screen.component.css']
    })
    export class MainScreenComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.utcTime();
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
      }

       utcTime(): void {
        setInterval(function() {
            this.myDate = new Date();
            console.log(this.myDate); // just testing if it is working
        }, 1000);
    }

      logOut() {
        this._globals.isAuthenticated = false;
        this._globals.loggedInUser = null;
        this._globals.token = null;
      }
```

Then change your date format as you wish using angular Date pipe